# Please translate: "Bacon Machine" (Apologies in advance for the somewhat silly question)

Tags: vocabulary, english-to-latin-translation

For a game I'm working on, I'm looking for a phrase in Latin that describes a robot created for the purpose of making synthetic bacon.

After looking at Latin grammar books, my current guess as to a reasonable translation is "Machina Lardum." Does that make sense? It's OK if it translates more closely to "Machine made of Bacon" as well.

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing to be decided here is how to translate "bacon" to Latin.
Different Romance languages seem to take very different approaches, and I am not familiar with a clear Latin word for it.
Studying the best word choice for "bacon" would make a nice separate question.

I will translate "bacon" as *lardum* here, as you suggest.
It is analogous with the French *lard*, and is not an unreasonable choice anyway.
I read *lardum* more as fat than meat, though.

In English you can simply put two words together to make a "bacon machine", but in Latin you cannot.
Therefore your suggested translation does not quite make sense.
I suggest forming the adjective *lardificus*, "bacon-making".
I find this appropriate because it is easy enough to understand, the role of bacon is clear (the machine is not made of it), and it is a single word instead of a clumsy relative clause.
This leads to the translation ***machina lardifica*** for "bacon-making machine".